# The return type 'SignUpScreen' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build a funtion who return Widget for persiting state but I am getting this error.

```
Future<Widget?> persiting () async {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges()
      .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return  SignUpScreen() ;
    } else {
      return  HomeScreen() ;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Future<Widget?> persiting () async {
    late bool hasUsers;
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        hasUsers = true;
      } else {
        hasUsers = false;
      }
    });
    return hasUsers ? SignUpScreen() : HomeScreen();
  }
```

Comment: It is not working I still getting error

Answer (score 0):

The exception showed because you are returning onject to the `.listen()` function instead of the `persiting()` function.

What you need to do is await to listen the stream inside the `presiting()` function.

```
Future<Widget?> persiting () async {
  try{
    Stream<User?> stream = await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges();
    bool hasUser = false;
    await stream.forEach((user){
      hasUser = user != null;
    });
    return hasUser? HomeScreen() : SignUpScreen();
  }catch(e){
    /// better do some handling if any network or unexpected error here
  }
}
```